# Не работает отлов входящих звонков с помощью broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

На Андроиде пытаюсь поймать событие входящий звонок. Сделал свой класс наследник `BroadcastRceiver` и в `onReceive` пытаюсь поймать входящий звонок. В манифесте объявил разрешение на чтение `phone_state`, объявил ресивер и у него в `IntentFilter'e` объявил  `Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE`. 
Ничего не ловит. В том числе и другие `action` тоже не ловит.
Если в моем рабочем сервисе сделать `registerReceiver`, то он прекрасно ловит броадкасты, но там я не нашел события входящий звонок.

Подскажите пожалуйста как быть..

Comment: Вместо всех этих букв приложите лучше манифест с частями, связанными с проблемой и код ресивера. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ. Создайте пример, который позволит воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: zTrap, спасибо что поправил мой вопрос, все именно так.
Дополню вопрос.
Вот то что в манифесте:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> - в области разрешений

и
<code>
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> <code> - внутри тега aplication

Comment: И вот слушатель:
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, PlayerService.class));
    }
}


Теги <code> из коментария выше не читайте, не понял как здесь выкладывать код

Comment: Добавляйте код редактированием вопроса (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментарии

Comment: Код манифеста в студию